# How to attach a maven plugin to a phase by default?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have a maven plugin that should run in the compile phase, so in the project that **consumes** my plugin, I have to do something like this:

```
<executions>
 <execution>
  <phase>compile</phase>
  <goals>
   <goal>my-goal</goal>
  </goals>
 </execution>
</executions>
```

What I need is to **by default** attach `my-goal` to the compile phase if the user has included my plugin already (ideally the above part wouldn't be necessary, just the plugin declaration).

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to avoid the executions part completely?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put an `@phase` [annotation](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-custom-plugin.html) in your Mojo classdef annotations.

The doc says:

```
@phase <phaseName>
```

This annotation specifies the default phase for this goal. If you add an execution for this goal to a pom.xml and do not specify the phase, Maven will bind the goal to the phase specified in this annotation by default.

If this doesn't work, I guess a JIRA is warranted.

Comment: Ok this works **partially** really, I don't have to explicit the `phase` part but I still need to put the whole `<execution>` crap

Comment: Oh, yea, definitely. To avoid that you need a custom lifecycle.

Answer (score 7):

Create an instance of src\main\resources\META-INF\plexus\components.xml in your plugin.

In there create a LifeCycle mapping for the artifact types that your want your Mojo to support. Make sure that it lists all the phases and plugins you want to support. Probably best to copy from the one from maven-core.jar.

Then add your plugin in to the appropriate LifeCycle(s) at the phase at which you want them built.

Eg the **consume-aar** Mojo added into the **compile** phase of the **aar** lifecycle.

```
<!--  Android archive (aar) support -->
<component>
  <role>org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.LifecycleMapping</role>
  <role-hint>aar</role-hint>
  <implementation>
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.DefaultLifecycleMapping
  </implementation>
  <configuration>
    <phases>
      <generate-sources>
        com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:generate-sources
      </generate-sources>
      <process-resources>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:resources</process-resources>
      <compile>
        com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:consume-aar,
        org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:compile
      </compile>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but it is an undocumented maven feature.

Use this `components.xml`:

```
<component-set>
  <components>
    <component>
        <role>org.apache.maven.lifecycle.Lifecycle</role>
        <implementation>org.apache.maven.lifecycle.Lifecycle</implementation>
        <role-hint>myplugin</role-hint>
        <configuration>
            <id>accurest</id>
            <phases>
                <phase>my-plugin-not-used-phase</phase>
            </phases>
            <default-phases>
                <compile>
                    my.package:my-plugin:${project.version}:my-goal
                </compile>
            </default-phases>
        </configuration>
    </component>
</components>
```

but your plugin need to be added with `<extensions>true</extensions>` to modify existing lifecycle.

More: [How to bind plugin mojos (goals) to few phases of default lifecycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36945610/how-to-bind-plugin-mojos-goals-to-few-phases-of-default-lifecycle)

Real project: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/blob/master/spring-cloud-contract-tools/spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin/src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/components.xml

Answer (score -5):

You associate plugin to maven lifecyle [goal](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html). The plugin configuration should be declared in *phase*.

For example if you wan to run some plugin during *build* phase you'll need to do something like this :

```
<project>
...
...
 <build>
   <plugin>
      **Configuration of plugin**
   </plugin>
 </build>
 </project>
```

Please read carefully about maven lifecycles here (it is fundamental for understanding of maven):
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

And then read about how to configure a plugin : http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html

P.S. Getting into logic of maven is not easy at the beginning. But it is rewarding afterwards.

Comment: So you mean I should put the `<execution` config inside the plugin's pom instead of the client's pom?