# How to bind plugin mojos (goals) to few phases of default lifecycle?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

My [custom maven plugin](https://github.com/Codearte/accurest-maven-plugin) have three goals (mojos):

- `convert` assigned to default phase: `process-test-resources`
- `generateStubs` assigned to default phase: `package`
- `generateTests` assigned to default phase: `generate-test-sources`

How to bind this three mojo to [default lifcycle phase](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/lifecycles.html#default_Lifecycle), so the user can simply use plugin without special configuration and any changes to project `packaging`?

User should simply add:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.codearte.accurest</groupId>
    <artifactId>accurest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
</plugin>
```

instead of

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.codearte.accurest</groupId>
    <artifactId>accurest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>convert</goal>
                <goal>generateStubs</goal>
                <goal>generateTests</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I can achieve this with `components.xml` like below, but this requires some ugly hacks (specifing not existing phase - `ugly-fix`) and I'm not sure, if this solution is working in all cases.

```
<component-set>
    <components>
        <component>
            <role>org.apache.maven.lifecycle.Lifecycle</role>
            <implementation>org.apache.maven.lifecycle.Lifecycle</implementation>
            <role-hint>accurest</role-hint>
            <configuration>
                <id>accurest</id>
                <phases>
                    <phase>ugly-fix</phase> // plugin fail without this
                </phases>
                <default-phases>
                    <process-test-resources>
                        io.codearte.accurest:accurest-maven-plugin:${project.version}:convert
                    </process-test-resources>
                    <generate-test-sources>
                        io.codearte.accurest:accurest-maven-plugin:${project.version}:generateTests
                    </generate-test-sources>
                    <package>
                        io.codearte.accurest:accurest-maven-plugin:${project.version}:generateStubs
                    </package>
                </default-phases>
            </configuration>
        </component>
    </components>
</component-set>
```

Is this correct? Is better way to do such configuration?

More information:

- Working [components.xml](https://github.com/Codearte/accurest-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/components.xml).
- Sample project which is using this configuration: https://github.com/mariuszs/gs-rest-service-accurest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that by replacing `ugly-fix` with correct goals in `<phases>` tag:

```
<component-set>
  <components>
    <component>
        <role>org.apache.maven.lifecycle.Lifecycle</role>
        <implementation>org.apache.maven.lifecycle.Lifecycle</implementation>
        <role-hint>accurest</role-hint>
        <configuration>
            <id>accurest</id>
            <phases>
                <process-test-resources>
                    io.codearte.accurest:accurest-maven-plugin:${project.version}:convert
                </process-test-resources>
                <generate-test-sources>
                    io.codearte.accurest:accurest-maven-plugin:${project.version}:generateTests
                </generate-test-sources>
                <package>
                    io.codearte.accurest:accurest-maven-plugin:${project.version}:generateStubs
                </package>
            </phases>
            <default-phases>
                <process-test-resources>
                    io.codearte.accurest:accurest-maven-plugin:${project.version}:convert
                </process-test-resources>
                <generate-test-sources>
                    io.codearte.accurest:accurest-maven-plugin:${project.version}:generateTests
                </generate-test-sources>
                <package>
                    io.codearte.accurest:accurest-maven-plugin:${project.version}:generateStubs
                </package>
            </default-phases>
        </configuration>
    </component>
</components>
```

Comment: This still looks like hack

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is the `defaultPhase` attribute of the `Mojo` annotation, see https://maven.apache.org/components/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-annotations/ for all the details.

Comment: No, that's not it, OP wants the plugin to be executed without declaring any `<execution>` in the POM. A `defaultPhase` requires an execution.

Comment: Ah, got it. That would indeed mean that you have to introduce a packaging type with a lifecycle.

Comment: Yeah and that's the second thing.. OP wants it to works automagically with whatever packaging in the default lifecycle (not their own). :) (that's where I'm stuck, without having to copy-paste the whole `default-bindings.xml` from maven core)

Comment: Not possible. And I wouldn't advice to adjust the lifecycle, just leave that up to the packaging plugin. Simply picture this: what would happen if every build-plugin would rewrite the lifecycle? I'm pretty sure most Maven users know how to bind plugin goals to phases, especially with a prepared copy-paste example :)

Comment: That's what I figured yeah, but thanks for your confirmation :).

Comment: @RobertScholte Not possible, but works in my example - maven bug? :) I dont want to rewrite the lifecycle. I simply want to inject additional goals into existing one - and I think this will be really useful thing...

Comment: @MᴀʀɪᴜsᴢS In your example, you have a custom packaging with a lifecycle that involves your 3 phases (and so it works the intended way). This is different that invoking your plugin goals for all packaging of the default lifecycle.

Comment: @Tunaki Im pretty sure it works this way - invokes my plugin goal for all packaging

Comment: @MᴀʀɪᴜsᴢS It doesn't, if you test with a `jar` packaging for example and you have `<role-hint>jar</role-hint>` in your `components.xml`, you'll see they are the only one invoked and the other default phases for the normal `jar` are not invoked.

Comment: same answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213526/how-to-attach-a-maven-plugin-to-a-phase-by-default

Comment: @Tunaki: Why would you want to change my `components.xml`. It works with different packaging because it has wrong `role-hint`.

Comment: @Hishamkh This is not the same, I have already binded all goals to default phases.

Comment: @Tunaki change packaging to war in my sample project, it works! https://github.com/mariuszs/gs-rest-service-accurest. So, to summarize all of this: this is bug in maven and there is no solution. yes?